# React, how to return at index 0 if the index is bigger than array length

Tags: reactjs

I am making a photo slider in React using class components.

How can I acesse the variable photos from the nextSlide and previousSlide?

I tried to move the variable Photos up next to the state but it is throwing me an error like "const can be used in type scipt"

Thank you if you have any sugesstion

```
export default class Gallery extends Component {
    
    state = { index: 0 } 

    nextSlid() {
        this.setState({index: this.state.index +1})
    }

    previousSlid() {
        this.setState({index: this.state.index -1})
    }
   
    render() {

    const photos = this.props.Photos;
    
        return (
            <div className="photo-box">
                <div className="left-icon" onClick={() => this.previousSlid()}>
                    <FiChevronLeft color='white' size={70}/>
                </div>
                <div className="right-icon" onClick={() => this.nextSlid()}>
                    <FiChevronRight color='white' size={70}/>
                </div>
                <img src={photos[this.state.index]} alt="Foto"/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

[Code Example photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A28z.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

```
nextSlid() {
    this.setState({index: (this.state.index +1) % photos.length })
}

previousSlid() {
    this.setState({index: (this.state.index -1) % photos.length })
}
```

Comment: Thank you whery much Dawid, but the problem the i'am actually having is with photos, as you can see im my code example I have my variable of photos under the render() so i can't acesse this variable, is there any way I can acesse this variable from the two functions who are up, thank you very much

Comment: simply move this line *const photos = this.props.Photos;* outside of render, e.g.

export default class Gallery extends Component {
    
  state = { index: 0 } 
  const photos = this.props.Photos;
  ...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Dawid, unfurtunatelly I can't acesse the photos variable, and moving it up it throwes an error !